# Implicit differentiation different results after multiplying by expression

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find $\frac{dy}{dx} $ for $\frac{ln(y)}{x}=x+y$.

Differentiating as is (i.e., quotient rule), I get: $y'=\frac{x^2 y + y\,ln(y)}{x-x^2y}$.

If I first multiply both sides by *x* to then differentiate $ln(y)=x^2+xy$, I get $y'=\frac{2xy+y^2}{1-xy}$.

These should be equivalent but I cannot manipulate them to show that.  In fact, I tried taking the difference between the two in WolframAlpha just to prove they were the same but do not get zero.

I confirmed the derivatives with WolframAlpha but cannot figure out why they don't match.

Comment: Aside:  Can someone tell me how to put a space between expressions?

Comment: Probably you just made a technical algebraic mistake. Check your calculations. I will also check them a bit later.

Comment: You get a (small) space in mathematical text by using \, A somewhat larger space by \quad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{x^2 y + y\ln(y)}{x-x^2y}= \frac{x y + y\frac{\ln(y)}{x}}{1-xy}$$
Using the original equation this equals
$$\frac{x y + y(x+y)}{1-xy} = \frac{2x y + y^2}{1-xy}$$

Comment: Ok, that was pretty trivial...  not sure what I did wrong - I feel quite dense now.  Any idea why WolframAlpha does not give zero for the difference?  
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E2y%2Bylny%29%2F%28x-x%5E2y%29+-+%282xy%2By%5E2%29%2F%281-xy%29

Comment: @Greg I don't know much about Mathematica, but did you tell the program that it may substitute $\ln(y)/x = y+x$? And sometimes you just don't see the wood for the trees..